# How do I exclude specific .dlls from Visual Studio 2003 C++ .NET?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, dll, compiler-construction

How do I exclude specific .dlls from Visual Studio 2003 C++ .NET?
During release build I get the following warnings.
Any help is appreciated.

```
Generating Code...
Linking...
LINK : warning LNK4089: all references to 'ADVAPI32.dll' discarded by /OPT:REF
LINK : warning LNK4089: all references to 'SHELL32.dll' discarded by /OPT:REF
LINK : warning LNK4089: all references to 'SHLWAPI.dll' discarded by /OPT:REF
LINK : warning LNK4089: all references to 'comdlg32.dll' discarded by /OPT:REF
LINK : warning LNK4089: all references to 'ole32.dll' discarded by /OPT:REF
```

Thank You.

Comment: there's no harm in those warnings.  can't you just ignore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of VS is really old, not sure if this applies.  But in VS2005/8 you would have to prevent inheriting the settings from the "Core Windows Library" project property sheet.  Which you'd do by either removing the sheet from the project or setting the Linker + Input setting to:

```
$(noinherit) kernel32.lib user32.lib
```

etcetera, listing all the .libs you really use.